# How to avoid this nested if statement?

Tags: c++, coding-style, software-design

I want to check if **one** file exists in two different paths. If the first one doesn't, check the second.

```
filepath1 = "/path1/file.txt"
filepath2 = "/path2/file.txt"
file_descriptor = open(filepath1)

if ( !file_descriptor.open() )
{
    print("file 1 did not work");
   
    //try file 2
    file_descriptor = open(filepath2);
    if( !file_descriptor.open() )
    {
        print("could not open file 2. exiting.");
        return false;
    }
}

//we get here and file_descriptor should point to a valid file
read_file(file_descriptor);
return true;
```

How can I avoid the nested `if` statement? Preferably, I'd like to not nest the `if` statements for readability.
The problem here is that if the first one does work, I don't want it to check the second `if` statement.

I thought about using:

- `goto` (I want to avoid this)
- boolean to check if one works (but now I'm introducing extra variables)

Comment: Honestly, it seems fine as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this pattern is pretty general: you can try as many paths as you wish:

```
auto filepath1 = "/path1/file.txt";
auto filepath2 = "/path2/file.txt";
// We assume file_descriptor has been declared earlier

for (const auto fpath: {filepath1, filepath2})
{
   file_descriptor = open(fpath)
   if (file_descriptor.open()) 
      break;
   else
      printf("file %s did not work\n", fpath);  
}
if (!file_descriptor.open()) return false;  // or throw

read_file(file_descriptor);
return true;
```

Comment: @bruno I think the point is not in the *number* of if's, but in aesthetics, legibility, maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care about which file is open you can do

```
filepath1 = "/path1/file.txt"
filepath2 = "/path2/file.txt"

if (!(file_descriptor = open(filepath1)).open() &&
    !(file_descriptor = open(filepath2)).open())
{
    print("could not open file 1 nor 2. exiting.");
    return false;
}
...
```

else if you *really* want only one `if` you can do

```
filepath1 = "/path1/file.txt"
filepath2 = "/path2/file.txt"

if (!(file_descriptor = open(filepath1)).open() &&
    (print("file 1 did not work"),
     !(file_descriptor = open(filepath2)).open()))
{
    print("could not open file 2. exiting.");
    return false;
}
...
```

but this makes the code less clear than with the two `if`s

P.S. do not think about using `goto`

Comment: @leengi I use the fact `(expr1, expr2, ... exprn)` executes the expressions in order and values the value of *exprn*

Comment: The second version assumes that `print()` returns value.

Comment: @Peter no, the function can be *void*, but I assume *print* is not a macro or it produces an expression, only the last expression in () must have a value

Comment: @bruno in the first option you showed, wouldn't the file_descriptor always point to the second path? this means if the first path is the correct one, the file descriptor will still always point to the second path, causing an error.

Comment: @leengi no, if the first path is correct then `!(file_descriptor = open(filepath1)).open()` is false and the `&&` is false without executing `!(file_descriptor = open(filepath2)).open()`. In a form `a && b` *b* is not executed if *a* is false, this is the difference with `a & b` where both *a* and *b* are executed whatever each values